# Drop columns if cells are strings

Tags: python

I have a dataset named "table" and I would like to delete all columns whose cells contain strings (these columns contain strings such as, for example, "A","N","N'", etc) from column 17 onwards. I used the function drop

`table.drop(columns=[0,1]`

to delete some other columns I needed, but I am having trouble to understand how I am going to use it to delete various non identified columns, as the criteria is the cell of the column to have or not to have a string (from column 17 to the total number of columns of the dataset).

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: are you using pandas DataFrame ?

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the datatype for each column to determine if the column needs to be dropped. To do this you can drop columns using [select_dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,], 'b': ['a','b','c'], 'c':['d', 2, 3]})
df = df.select_dtypes(exclude=['object'])
df
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3
```

To only drop columns after a certain number you can split the df into two df's and drop the columns from the one you want to.